# Woocommerce change color of backorder message

Tags: wordpress, text, woocommerce, colors

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the text of the backorder message. 
For now I'm using this code:

```
function so_42345940_backorder_message( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $text = __( 'Text here', 'your-textdomain' );
    }

    return $text;
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'so_42345940_backorder_message', 10, 2 );
```

It's green now and the same color as when it's available. Customers are missing it so I would like to give it another color

Thanks in advance!
[The green text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Osp.png)

Comment: Please provide screenshot, in which place you want to change color.

Comment: Just the text behind availability on the product page where I want the backorder part to be orange or red, because its same color as in stock now. I can make a screenshot ppl,  but my site is in Dutch so I dont know if its much use

Comment: yes don't worries for dutch language, please provide screenshot, and mark the place where you want to change color.

Comment: I've added it to the main post (The green text here)

Comment: ok got your questions, please send me site link so i can give you updated hook or class name.

Answer (score 0):

To do it with just CSS, there is a class name in some themes, The class name can be different for each theme so you can do this :

Enable backorder for a product and then on the product's page search the page source code for the word "backorder", for me (Nitro Theme) the div with product id which wraps the whole page content has the class "onbackorder" so here's the CSS :

```
.onbackorder .stock.in-stock{
    background: #fd5f28 !important;
}
```